# How to count total items in @ManyToMany

Tags: java, many-to-many, jpa-2.0

I got my model

```
public class Comic implements Serializable {

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@ManyToMany
private Set<User> owners;

(lots of blah blah blah)    
}
```

and I want to query for total numer of owners of any comic I have, other speaking simply for a number of rows in joining table. But I have no idea how to refernce this table? How should this query in JPA2.0 would look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select count(o) from Comic c join c.owners o
```